# Relative frequency from dataframe with 3 columns of raw data?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, frequency, frequency-analysis

New to Python (& [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com)), I am struggling to find a solution to take my `['Product_Name', 'Date_of_Sale', 'Quantity']` data and output the relative frequencies of the daily quantity frequencies per product.

As an example, Product 1 sells 8 units (Day1), 6 units (Day2), 6 (Day 3), 5 (Day 4), 8 (Day 5), 7 (Day 6), 6 (Day 7) over 7 days, giving relative frequencies for Product 1 of `{5 units : 0.142, 6 : 0.429, 7 : 0.142, 8 : 0.286}`.

How can I do this for all products for a period?

Comment: Please post a sample of your dataframe, df.head() should be good

Answer (score 2):

Normalize the value counts:

```
>>> df['Product1'].value_counts(normalize=True)
6    0.428571
8    0.285714
7    0.142857
5    0.142857
Name: Product1, dtype: float64
```

Doing this "for all products for a period" depends on the structure of your data.  You would need to provide a sample and your expected result.

Comment: Thanks, Alexander. The answer from rahlf23 solves it. Thanks, anyway.

Comment: If there are NaNs in the data, that answer will give the wrong result. If you want a dictionary (it isn't clear from your question), just tag `.to_dict()` to my answer above.

Comment: OK, thank you. I will have a play with your initial response, see where it takes me and come back if problems.

Answer (score 1):

Use `value_counts()` and `to_dict()`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Day': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
    'Product1': [8, 6, 6, 5, 8, 7, 6]})

df['Product1'].value_counts().div(df.shape[0]).to_dict()
```

Yields:

```
{6: 0.42857142857142855, 8: 0.2857142857142857, 7: 0.14285714285714285, 5: 0.14285714285714285}
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks rahlf23